# I took a log of this equation , is this correct?

Tags: logarithms

$$\prod_i \frac{\prod_jexp(a_{ij}\theta- \delta_{ij})}{\sum_hexp(a_{ih}\theta- \delta_{ih})}$$

Taking log

$$\sum_i\sum_j {(a_{ij}\theta- \delta_{ij})}-{\sum_ilog\sum_hexp(a_{ih}\theta- \delta_{ih})}$$

Derivative with respect to $\theta$

$$\sum_i\sum_j {(a_{ij})}-{\sum_i\frac{(a_{ih}exp((a_{ih}\theta- \delta_{ih}))}{\sum_hexp(a_{ih}\theta- \delta_{ih})}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, because taking
$$
\log\left(\sum_h \mathrm{e}^{a_{ih}}\right) 
$$
can not be separated so I would expect an exponential in there
e.g. in general
$$
\log(a + b) \neq \log(a) + \log(b) 
$$

The solution would be
$$
\sum_i\sum_j (\alpha_{ij}\theta -\delta_{ij}) - \sum_i\log\sum_h\left[\mathrm{e}^{\alpha_{ih}\theta -\delta_{ih}}\right]
$$

Comment: what happened to the \sum_h?

Comment: Sorry a copy and paste error will update.

Comment: i also tried taking derivative of this , can you please check if it looks good?
https://imgur.com/a/1PvwkcN

Comment: i also added the derivative to original post can u pls check

Comment: Why does the \sum_h go inside exp? it was outside \exp... i am confused

Comment: It is best to have a different question, as now my answer is only a partial answer.

Comment: i will add a different question , can you just please tell why did summation go inside exp?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718074/tried-taking-the-log-and-then-derivative-of-this-equation-is-this-correct

Comment: @ujjwaltyagi I changed it :)

Comment: thank u so much u saved my life