# Tried taking the log and then derivative of this equation, is this correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, logarithms

$$\prod_i \frac{\prod_j\exp(a_{ij}\theta- \delta_{ij})}{\sum_h\exp(a_{ih}\theta- \delta_{ih})}$$

Taking log

$$\sum_i\sum_j {(a_{ij}\theta- \delta_{ij})}-{\sum_i\log\sum_h\exp(a_{ih}\theta- \delta_{ih})}$$

Derivative with respect to $\theta$

$$\sum_i\sum_j {(a_{ij})}-{\sum_i\frac{(a_{ih}\exp((a_{ih}\theta- \delta_{ih}))}{\sum_h\exp(a_{ih}\theta- \delta_{ih})}}$$

Comment: this is different question than before, the question before asked about log and now its about derivative

Comment: I couldnt do that because first i had to figure out how to take log, i didnt know what would be log so i cannot take the derivative of that. Once i found out what will be the log in last post i put a question about derivative also, the person in last post advised me to make a different post here. I just wanted to take log and differentiate this and nothing more

Comment: @Ajay to defend the OP - I suggested to add another question as the original was answered and accepted. Then a follow up was added with the derivative. Now it looks the same because the original was updated and then copied to this one. I thought this was the behaviour we were expecting, if a follow up question was asked it should be in another one?

Comment: is my derivative correct?

Comment: @Chinny84 No need to defend the OP, i'm not attacking them :)

Comment: @ujjwaltyagi Sorry, I didn't read the comments form the answer on the other posts. It would be helpful if you linked the previous post above.

Comment: @Ajay I know :) - my words were not that careful.

Comment: @Ajay https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718074/tried-taking-the-log-and-then-derivative-of-this-equation-is-this-correct

Comment: @ujjwaltyagi I mean link it above in the body of your question.